# Microsoft Azure Tools: Port conflict with existing application?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I am using TFS a azure application in server, and I found this error , I couldn't resolve this since then,

```
Microsoft Azure Tools: Failed to initialize Microsoft Azure storage emulator. Port conflict with existing application.
```

Can anyone please help me in providing me steps to resolve this please.

Comment: Hi, does my answer able to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default, Azure storage emulator is using port number **10000**, **10001**, **10002** for Blob, Queue and Table services respectively.

If you have existing applications using these port numbers and can't be changed, you can resolve the port conflict by changing Azure storage emulator default port numbers to avoid port conflict as the steps below:

1. Stop your Azure storage emulator service
2. Go to your storage emulator default installation folder, which is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator`
3. Open the **`AzureStorageEmulator.exe.config`** file for edit
4. Edit the default port numbers as shown below
   [image]
5. Start your Azure storage emulator service.

You should expect the Azure storage emulator to start successfully without any port conflict.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have tried all possible ways, Finally re installed VS and again started Storage EMulator and this is wokring for me. I tried your way too.Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Also, please note that you can't use standard UseDevelopmentStorage=true connection string. You must specify custom endpoints in your connection string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119066/change-running-ip-of-azure-storage-emulator#answer-37120309

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled VS Update 5 and tried again and it was working fine now.

Few things to make note is:

1. Try changing Port in AzureStorageEmulator
2. make sure if your (localdb)\v11.0 is connected in your SQL Server Object Explorer.
3. You can Manually Start ,Stop, Create localDB Instance (If needed).
4. If nothing works, Try re installing Visual Studio as you may have missed any bindings.

I have re-installed Visual Studio Update5 and restarted my system, its working for me now.